# string match with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

hey i have a requirement , where i have to compare a  file name of the uploaded file to a standardized file name format specified by our client

Standardize Format      FW12_CommunicatedArticles.xlsx
 any file that user uploads should be comply to the following format FW12_CommunicatedArticles.xlsx
the integars (1, 2 in FW can change  but the rest of the name should exactly match the format specified)

for example a valid file upload can be FW13_CommunicatedArticles.xlsx , FW23_CommunicatedArticles.xlsx    etc , etc

invalid upload  = sW13_CommunicatedArticles.xlsx , FW13_CommuArticles.xlsx  , FW1324_CommuArticles.xlsx etc etc

only the value of the integars can be different , the strings length , its arrangement and everything has to be exactly the same as specified by the convention i have to do the validating through javascript , can you guys please help me devising the proper regular expression validation to tackle this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple regexp will do the trick. `\d` will match a digit.

```
/^FW\d\d_CommunicatedArticles\.xlsx$/.test(filename)
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/FDZ4m/). Press F1 and Esc in Chrome to show the console.

Comment: Point in your equation match any char. Use "\."instead.

Comment: @Prodigy: right, the jsfiddle was correct, and tested for that. Updated.

Comment: its not working i wrote the following code  var s = "FW12_CommunicatedArticles.xlsx";
            var regexp = new RegExp("/^FW\d\d_CommunicatedArticles\.xlsx$/");

            if (!regexp.test(s)) {
                alert('Uploaded file for communicated articles  for fall winter does not comply to the file naming standard');

            }

Comment: If you use `"` in the RegExp constructor, then you need to escape the backslashes. Better to use the `/` separator. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description